# Less navbar a:active does not work

Tags: less, joomla3.0

Gentle men (and likewise women),

I'm stuck with a nasty Less problem I can't figure out.

Here's the code:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.nav > li > a:link {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav > li > a:visited {
  color: #ccc;
  background: blue;
}
.nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: pink;
}
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:active {
  color: #000;
  background: yellow;
}

.nav > li .current {
  color: black!important;
  background: skyblue!important;
}
```

I'm new to Less, my first (minor) problem is how to nest this code properly.

But the real problem is that a:active and a:focus do not work. Nothing whatsoever. a:link does, but not what it's supposed to do. I want the font-colour to be white, it shows up blue. Checking the generated code shows in line 1089, but weirdly enough Firebug shows that colour crossed out - it shouldn't work. 
I want a:active and/or a:focus with font-colour #000, but that does not work. 
a:active does show up but goes away in a split second.
I tried the .current class, as it shows up in Firebug, but that one doesn't work at all.

You can check the code out on http://www.test.dgdesk.com.

It's a Joomla site based on Joostrap, with Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

This is a css conflict.

[image]

The color from `.sidebar-right`'s nav styles overrides the color from the general nav styles.

You can fix the issue by defining a more specific class for the nav you are updating, or by updating the sidebar styles directly.

Comment: That helps only partly. I deactivate that line, but the a:active remains absent. a:hover works excellent though.